# Are Float32Array operations converted to double?

Tags: javascript, c++

If I have this javascript code:

```
var a = new Float32Array(4);
var b = new Float32Array(4);
var r = new Float32Array(4);

//fill here "a" and "b" with random numbers

r[0] = a[0] + b[0];
r[1] = a[1] - b[1];
r[2] = a[2] * b[2];
r[3] = a[3] / b[3];
```

Are those floats converted to double before doing the operations?
If I run the same float32 operations on c++ and javascript code (no sqrt(), sin(), tan()...etc) will the floats maintain the same value on those two languages?

Comment: @RaymondChen obviously. Deleting my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript math operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) are always done with 64-bit doubles. Typed arrays are about storage interpretation; once a value is retrieved from a typed array it's a plain JavaScript number.

There are cases where the value in a number is *treated* as an integer, but the numbers are still 64-bit doubles.